# How do I solve $\lim_{x \to 0-} \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}}{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0-} \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^\frac{1}{x}}{x^2}
$$

I encountered something like this during class and I can't quite remember what my teacher said. I think it was something along the lines of "$e^(1/x)$ gets faster to $0$ so the limit is $0$"

Comment: use l'hopitals twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both series and L'hospital fail here.  (At least when applied in the usual way.)  But let $y = 1/x$ so that $y\to -\infty$ when $x\to 0^-.$  Then your limit is:

$$\lim_{y\to -\infty} \frac{e^y}{\frac{1}{y^2}} =  \lim_{y\to -\infty} \frac{y^2}{e^{-y}}. $$

Now you can use L'hospital's rule to get

$$=\lim_{y\to -\infty} \frac{2y}{-e^{-y}}  = \lim_{y\to -\infty} 
\frac{2}{e^{-y}}  = 0.$$

Comment: I understand, thx a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Make the substitution $\displaystyle u = -\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

As $x \to 0-$, $\frac{1}{x} \to -\infty$ which means that $e^{\frac{1}{x}} \to 0$ as $x \to 0-$. Therefore, the whole expression will tend towards $0$ as $x \to 0-$

Comment: How does one know that "the whole expression will tend to $0$."  You need to prove this here.

Comment: Since the numerator is $0$, it doesn't matter what's underneath. The result will be $0$.

Comment: You need to show the indeterminate form approaches $0$.  You haven't.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Note that for $x<0$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}&=\frac{1}{x^2e^{1/|x|}}\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{x^2\,\frac{1}{6|x|^3}}
\end{align}$$

since $e^t\ge \frac16 t^3$ for $t>0$.

Comment: This shows "how/why" $e^{1/x}$ goes to $0$ faster than $x^2$.

Comment: Was the "HINT" useful? If not, I am happy to either elaborate or delete. Which is better for you?